# Thinkscript: Recursive Counter

Tags: recursion, counter, thinkscript

I'd like to create a scan in thinkorswim where it returns stocks that have closed higher then when it opened for 4 days or more out of the last 5 days.

This is the current code I have, but I don't know if it is correct or how to limit it to only the last 5 days:

```
def count = if (close > open) then 1 else 0;
rec counter = counter[1] + count;

plot scan = 
counter >= 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives:

- Did you want the last 4 or 5 days consecutively to close higher? If so, this option will check for that:

```
# set aggregation because you want the last 5 days,
#   not the last 5 bars regardless of time set
def closeVal = close(period=AggregationPeriod.DAY);
def openVal = open(period=AggregationPeriod.DAY);

# define the condition you want met (it'll check for this on every bar)
def countCondition = closeVal > openVal;

# sum the last 4 bars (days in this case, due to aggregation setting)
# note: the indexes are pointing to the current bar, 1 bar prior, 2 bars prior, and 3 bars prior
# also, each `true` condition will equal 1; `false` is 0
def sumLast4 = countCondition + countCondition[1] + countCondition[2] + countCondition[3];

# ensure last 4 all closed higher than they opened
def last4Condition = (sumLast4 == 4);

# if the last 4 days met the condition, then add in the 5th day prior;
# else, just use the sum of those last 4
def total = if last4Condition then sumLast4 + countCondition[5] else sumLast4;

# plot the final desired condition:
#   at least the last 4 days closed higher than their open
plot scan = total >= 4;
```

---

---

- If the days closing higher don't need to be consecutive:

```
# set aggregation because you want the last 5 days, not the last 5 bars
def closeVal = close(period=AggregationPeriod.DAY);
def openVal = open(period=AggregationPeriod.DAY);

# define the condition you want met (it'll check for this on every bar)
def countCondition = closeVal > openVal;

# sum the last 5 bars (days in this case, due to aggregation setting)
# note: each `true` condition will equal 1; `false` is 0
def sumLast5 = countCondition + countCondition[1] + countCondition[2] + countCondition[3] + countCondition[4];

# plot the final desired match
plot scan = sumLast5 > 3;
```

---

---

- Using `fold`, ThinkScript's equivalent of a `for` loop. This one finds 4 out of the last 5, but not necessarily consecutive:

```
# set the length - using `input` means you can edit in the scan settings
input length = 5;

# set aggregation because you want the last 5 days, not the last 5 bars
def closeVal = close(period=AggregationPeriod.DAY);
def openVal = open(period=AggregationPeriod.DAY);

# declare a `counter` variable, but we'll set its value in the `if` statement
def counter;

# ensure all data is available by checking to see if the 5th bar back is a number 
if !isNaN(closeVal[length - 1]){
    # we have a number, so let's fold...
    # `with count = 0` initializes a variable called `count` to 0
    # for i = 0 to length... (i will go 0 thru 4; it ends when it sees 5)
    # if closeVal[i] (the closeVal i bars back) is less than openVal[i]
    # then `count = count + 1` else `count` just remains the same as it last was
    # when the loop is done, put the `count` value into the `counter` variable
    counter = fold i = 0 to length with count = 0 do if getValue(closeVal, i) > getValue(openVal, i) then count + 1 else count;
}
else {
    # if the 5th bar back wasn't a number, we can't calculate
    #   so, simply set the counter to indicate it's Not a Number
    counter = Double.NaN;
}

plot scan = counter > 3;
```

*edited to clarify that a `true` value equals 1, while a `false` value equals 0

Comment: This is interesting. 
I assuming the indexing would still would if I did something like : `def countCondition = closeVal > openVal and closeVal > closeVal[1];`, which is adding the condition that today's close is higher than yesterday's close.

Answer (score 1):

easy way:

```
#comment: declare five Booleans for each of five days
def candle1 = close[5] > open[5];
def candle2 = close[4] > open[4];
def candle3 = close[3] > open[3];
def candle4 = close[2] > open[2];
def candle5 = close[1] > open[1];
#
#comment: add up all the green candles(value == 1) and red candles(value == 0)
def sumofgreencandles = candle1 + candle2 + candle3+ candle4 + candle5;
#
#comment: return one if 4 or five candles are green, zero if 3 or fewer are green-
plot fouroffivegreen= if sumofgreencandles > 3 then low else double.nan;
#
#comment: add an arrow to graph where condition exists:
fouroffivegreen.setpaintingstrategy(paintingstrategy.arrow_UP);
fouroffivegreen.setdefaultcolor(color.cyan);
```

This will place a cyan colored arrow under any bar or point where at least the last four of five periods closed higher than open.  I know it looks clunky, but if you use a fold statement, it is much slower and will delay the rendering of your charts.